# How to validate a php form with java script, that is on everypage of my site

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

The problem i'm having is Im trying to get the contact.php to validate a contact form that is now in the bottom of every page in my site. It worked great with just validating one page and having a hard URL to take them back to. the troubleing code is this.

```
/* In case of no valid input go back  */
if ($p1==""||$p2==""||$p3==""||$p5==""||$n0!=0||$f0<7||$NL==0||$p7=="") {
    header($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].$report); 
}else{$report='noerror';}
```

Ive also tryed this:

```
/* In case of no valid input go back  */
if ($p1==""||$p2==""||$p3==""||$p5==""||$n0!=0||$f0<7||$NL==0||$p7=="") {
    header($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].$report); 
}else{$report='noerror';}
```

This is the original code that worked for one page:

```
/* In case of no valid input go back  */
if ($p1==""||$p2==""||$p3==""||$p5==""||$n0!=0||$f0<7||$NL==0||$p7=="") {
   header('Location:estimate_page.php?'.$report);
}else{$report='noerror';}
```

I could just make a new "contact.php" page for every page that has the form in the footer, but thats stupid if i can just make this work. Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking in the right direction with javascript/jQuery -- it will allow you to catch the invalid fields before submitting / changing pages. Much better user experience. Only submit when fields are validated.

Here is a link for how to do simple field validation testing with jQuery:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4g4e/7/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
One: <input type="text" id="f1"><br />
Two: <input type="text" id="f2"><br />
Three: <input type="text" id="f3"><br />
Four: <input type="text" id="f4"><br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Go" />
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
var chkFld, arrAll = {'One':'f1','Two':'f2','Three':'f3','Four':'f4'};

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    var errMsg='', badFlds='', firstBad='';
    for(var key in arrAll){
        chkFld = '#'+arrAll[key];
        $(chkFld).removeClass('error');
        if ($(chkFld).val() ==''){
            $(chkFld).addClass('error');
            //alert('Please complete field ' + arrAll[key] );
            errMsg += '*' + key + '\n';
            if (firstBad=='') firstBad=chkFld;
        }
    }
    if (errMsg != '') {
        alert(errMsg);
        $(firstBad).focus();
    }
}); //END mybutt.click
```

Note that the above example uses jQuery, so you must reference the jQ libraries (usually inside the head tags, something like this:)

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here is what the full HTML would look like:

```
<?php
    //Any initial PHP code goes here
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //javascript
        var chkFld, arrAll = {'One':'f1','Two':'f2','Three':'f3','Four':'f4'};
        $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#mybutt').click(function() {
                    var errMsg='', badFlds='', firstBad='';
                    for(var key in arrAll){
                        chkFld = '#'+arrAll[key];
                        $(chkFld).removeClass('error');
                        if ($(chkFld).val() ==''){
                            $(chkFld).addClass('error');
                            //alert('Please complete field ' + arrAll[key] );
                            errMsg += '*' + key + '\n';
                            if (firstBad=='') firstBad=chkFld;
                        }
                    }
                    if (errMsg != '') {
                        alert(errMsg);
                        $(firstBad).focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                    //If it gets to here, it passed validation
                        $('#yourForm').submit();
                }); //END mybutt.click()

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <form id="yourForm">
        One: <input type="text" id="f1" /><br />
        Two: <input type="text" id="f2" /><br />
        Three: <input type="text" id="f3" /><br />
        Four: <input type="text" id="f4" /><br />
    </form>
    <input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Click Me">

</body>
</html>
```

Note that, using the above scenario, no further PHP code would execute ***until*** the form is submitted, using the manual `$('#yourForm').submit();` statement.

Comment: Thanks for replying, though, the form is validating im not sure how to make it loop back to the page it is currently on instead of to a hard URL, with some sort of php_self or something

Comment: That depends on the *event* that launches the validation code. If you are using a `<input type="submit"` button, then you must put `return false;` or `event.preventDefault();` ([see here](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/)) when validation fails in order to return to the page without submitting. Otherwise, the form will continue submitting regardless. Of course, there is no **need** to use the `type="submit"` button -- in these days of jQuery, you can use an `<input type="button" id="mybutton"` control just as well.

Comment: Note: If using the `type="button"` input element, you just add the jQuery statement `$('#yourFormID').submit()` at the appropriate place when ready for the submit to actually go ahead. (i.e. after successful validation) Waaaay more control that way, yes? The `type="submit"` input is so... 2010...

Comment: ok, so ill put the whole code, and you can maybe tell me how to make the validation use the page its on instead of the hard URL to return the user to that had invalid input.

Comment: /* In case of no valid input go back  */
    if ($p1==""||$p2==""||$p3==""||$p5==""||$n0!=0||$f0<7||$NL==0||$p7=="") {
    header('Location:estimate_page.php?'.$report);
    }else{$report='noerror';}

Comment: That is PHP code. PHP code *finishes* executing when the website is ready for user interaction, and only begins again when the website is *finished* user interaction. Not waht you want. The code I posted is jQuery (JavaScript) and **can** interact with the user. I will update the example code to show where/how to use it.

Comment: One should be cautious and note that **client side JS-based validation cannot be a substitute of server side validation**. A user can turn off JS and effectively submit an entirely invalid form. Instead, use **both** JS and PHP to validate the form — JS to ensure a smooth user experience, but PHP as a fail safe catch all.

Comment: @Terry Very good point, Terry. Thanks for adding that. So, for best UX, do initial field validation in js, but *double-check* in PHP. However, if you *only* do PHP, then there is no way to return control to user without refreshing page (and losing everything user has already entered).